# How to configure matplotlib widget in python (x,y)

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, pyqt4

I was trying to configure matplotlib widget that is in Qtdesigner. The code is all working fine it's giving plot and stuff. But there just a small question. When i was trying to add plot following the instruction online. it seems like i have to use

```
self.ui.mplwidget.figure.add_subplot(111).plot([1,2,3],[2,3,4])
```

but what i thought was just using those API from matplotlib http://matplotlib.org/api/ which is something like following

```
self.ui.mplwidget.plot([1,2,3],[2,3,4])
```

it seems like "plot" is not an option after "mplwidget" but "figure" is. However, "plot" and "figure" are both given in API. I was wondering what is the reason for that? say, if i want to keep the plot on top of last plot every time i run this code, what should i say? Or what if i want to clear that plot which code should i enter?

Answer (score 0):

I think mplwidget is the QWidget object which contain the Figure object. If you want to do some plot:

Create an Axes object first,  which is the code `figure.add_subplot(111)`

And call methods of Axes object to do the plot. If you want to plot several lines, you need to use a variable to save the `Axes` object and just call `Axes.plot()` later:

```
self.ax = self.ui.mplwidget.figure.add_subplot(111)
self.ax.plot(...)
self.ax.plot(...)
```

If you want to clear the Axes, call `Axes.clear()`.

```
self.ax.clear()
```

If you want to clear the figure, call `figure.clear()`, and the add new `Axes` object.

```
self.ui.mplwidget.figure.clear()
self.ax = self.ui.mplwidget.figure.add_subplot(111)
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, i was wondering if there's a list of objects that i can use for this widget, i tried to search for it online ,but it seems like matplotlib API is all can find. Because i not sure which object i should use, if i want to add navigation tool bar in this widget.